# android:selectAllOnFocus in Jetpack Compose TextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Traditional `EditText` on Android supports [android:selectAllOnFocus](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:selectAllOnFocus) attribute, which causes its content to be selected when user, for example, clicks on the `EditText`.

How can this behavior be achieved when using `androidx.compose.material.TextField` in Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can collect the focus state from `MutableInteractionSource` and change the selection state depending on it:

```kotlin
var textFieldValue by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("Lorem ipsum")) }
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
val isFocused by interactionSource.collectIsFocusedAsState()
LaunchedEffect(isFocused) {
    textFieldValue = textFieldValue.copy(
        selection = if (isFocused) {
            TextRange(
                start = 0,
                end = textFieldValue.text.length
            )
        } else {
            TextRange.Zero,
        }
    )
}
TextField(
    value = textFieldValue,
    onValueChange = { textFieldValue = it },
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
)
```